# Firebase app is crashing when using removeValue()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When i use the following code...and press the remove button in the app, the value is removed in firebase database, but causes my app to crash.

```
    mSingleRemoveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                if(mPostKey!=null)
                {
                    System.out.println("The key is " + mPostKey);

                    mDatabase.child(mPostKey).removeValue();
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(BlogSingleActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(mainIntent);

                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("The key is empty");
                }

            }
```

Also when i remove *"mDatabase.child(mPostKey).removeValue();"* , the app is working fine, but obviously not removing the entry from my database.

**LOGCAT**

```
    08-01 19:42:51.093 32536-32536/com.vks_apps.blogs I/System.out: The key is -KqT82kPqOE_iq0UKHnm

                                                                --------- beginning of system
08-01 19:42:51.129 32536-4494/com.vks_apps.blogs V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
08-01 19:42:51.131 32536-32536/com.vks_apps.blogs D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-01 19:42:51.132 32536-32536/com.vks_apps.blogs E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.vks_apps.blogs.BlogSingleActivity$1.onDataChange(BlogSingleActivity.java:88)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
08-01 19:42:51.135 32536-4494/com.vks_apps.blogs D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, _sc=BlogSingleActivity, _si=-4635728123048285128, timestamp=1501596771132, fatal=1}]
08-01 19:42:51.157 32536-4494/com.vks_apps.blogs V/FA: Using measurement service
08-01 19:42:51.157 32536-4494/com.vks_apps.blogs V/FA: Connecting to remote service

                                                       --------- beginning of crash
08-01 19:42:51.378 32536-32536/com.vks_apps.blogs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.vks_apps.blogs, PID: 32536
                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.vks_apps.blogs.BlogSingleActivity$1.onDataChange(BlogSingleActivity.java:88)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
08-01 19:42:51.445 32536-5218/com.vks_apps.blogs I/FirebaseCrash: Sending crashes
08-01 19:42:52.021 32536-5218/com.vks_apps.blogs I/FirebaseCrash: Response code: 200
08-01 19:42:52.023 32536-5218/com.vks_apps.blogs I/FirebaseCrash: Report sent with crash report id: 6e22679504000000
```

Comment: Given the source of the problem in the stack trace, can you point out `BlogSingleActivity.java:88` in the code?

Comment: Vipul, please do not spam comments with links to your other questions. You've done that several places, here and on the answers below. That is annoying to other users and against our rules. If someone wants to find your other questions, they can see all of them listed in your profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you logcat sais, `Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()`, this means that something in this line of code is `null`:

```
mDatabase.child(mPostKey).removeValue();
```

The only thing  that can be null is `mPostKey`. Check for `nullity` before using `removeValue()` method.

```
if(mPostKey != null) {
    mDatabase.child(mPostKey).removeValue();
}
```

Also to remove a record from a Firebase database, make sure that mPostKey is not null. See where is became null.

Seeing the updated question in which `mPostKey` was displayed in the logcat `-KqT82kPqOE_iq0UKHnm`, the error that occurred at line 88 in `BlogSingleActivity` was the problem. The problem actually was that at line 88, `mPostKey` was used again causing the app to crash because of passing a null value into the `child()` method. `mPostKey != null` was added only for checking for nullity.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the callstack you can see that the problem is in `BlogSingleActivity$1.onDataChange()`. There you are calling the database and passing an empty value into `child()`.

Comment: That is the problem... The value is not null... Still it's giving this error.

Comment: Given the error message, on `BlogSingleActivity.java:88` you are passing an empty value into `child()`. Disagreeing with error messages has never gotten me very far.  But without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it is quite useful), it'll be hard to help you further.